# Changing Average of Seconds in minutes and seconds

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table below:

[image]

I am trying to get the average of "someNumber" (which is number of seconds)  per date and then convert that number into miutes and seconds.

So, I am drawing the graph below:

[image]

As you can see, I used the average filter and it calculated the average of "someNumber" per date. For instance, the average on 1st is 13. Now, how do I convert 13  into minutes and seconds so that I can display it as a tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure to get the average in seconds.

```
avg = AVERAGE(Table[SomeNumber])
```

Then create a measure for the tooltip lets call it `Time`, this helpful measure was created by  **@konstantinos** and **@smoupre** in the Power BI community blog.

```
Time = 
VAR Duration = [avg] // Here use the average measure created before
VAR Hours =
    INT ( Duration / 3600)
VAR Minutes =
    INT ( MOD( Duration - ( Hours * 3600 ),3600 ) / 60)
VAR Seconds =
    ROUNDUP(MOD ( MOD( Duration - ( Hours * 3600 ),3600 ), 60 ),0) 
VAR H =
    IF ( LEN ( Hours ) = 1, 
        CONCATENATE ( "0", Hours ),
        CONCATENATE ( "", Hours )
      )
VAR M =
    IF (
        LEN ( Minutes ) = 1,
        CONCATENATE ( "0", Minutes ),
        CONCATENATE ( "", Minutes )
    )
VAR S =
    IF (
        LEN ( Seconds ) = 1,
        CONCATENATE ( "0", Seconds ),
        CONCATENATE ( "", Seconds )
    )
RETURN
      CONCATENATE ( M, CONCATENATE ( ":", S ) )
```

Now use the `[Time]` measure as tooltip in your chart

[image]

Hope it helps.